# Running hibernate test is ok from eclipse but fails with gradle

Tags: hibernate, testing, gradle

I have some hibernate tests which run well from eclipse but, when I run them with gradle I see the following excerpt of stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Address is not mapped [delete from Address]
                at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
                at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
```

Address is one of my entity classes, which failed to be scanned by JPA as I can see

My project structure is this:

[image]

Do I need to do anything else so my hibernate tests work also when running with gradle?

Thanks,

UPDATE:added gradle build file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.32'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

task hibernateInstrumentation << {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'hibernateInstrumentation' ,
    classpath: project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath,
    classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask'){
    }
    ant.hibernateInstrumentation(verbose: 'true') {
        fileset(
                dir: "${project.buildDir}",
                include: '**/*.class'
                )
    }
    println("hibernate instrumentation")
}

compileJava.doLast { hibernateInstrumentation }
```

UPDATE 2: correct gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.32'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

compileJava.doLast {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'hibInstrument',
    classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask',
    classpath: project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath)
    ant.hibInstrument(verbose: 'true'){
        fileset(dir:"${buildDir}/classes"){ include(name: "**/*.class") }
    }
    println("hibernate instrumentation")
}

sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
//sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir

jar.duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
```

Comment: The last line is a no-op. `hibernateInstrumentation` shouldn't be its own task; instead, its code should go right into `compileJava.doLast { ... }`. I can't say if the code is correct, though. Another thing that's typically necessary is to set `sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir`. Same for `sourceSets.test`.

Comment: Peter by adding sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir the tests are working. Care to explain why? As far as I know the src/main/resources and src/test/resources are automatically on classpath. I mean why do they need to be set and what do they do exactly? Thank you

Comment: JPA expects that resources such as `persistence.xml` and the corresponding classes reside in the same dir or Jar, but Gradle uses different output dirs for resources and classes by default. If this change solves the problem, and `hibernateInstrumentation` is only referenced from `compileJava.doLast` as shown above, then it is redundant and can be deleted. (As I said, `compileJava.doLast { hibernateInstrumentation }` does nothing.)

Comment: PS: `sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` may lead to every file being included twice in the Jar. I can't tell offhand how to prevent that.

Comment: Ok Peter so only this is necessary for tests to work sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
. But indeed classes are added twice in jar.But, I don't know why because in the classes dir, are just once. So I don't know who copies them twice. Anyhow, I'm assuming that the jar plugin is copying from classes but also resources ( and considering that I have added to the resources the classes dir ) this is why I'm gettting them twice added. So I will search how to exclude either from resource/ classes when making the jar. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, the `java` plugin configures the `jar` task to include both the resources and the classes dir. The easiest solution is to set `jar.duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE`.

Comment: Hi Peter, I've tried jar.duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE and it works flawlessly. With these being said I can run my tests now from console too, and the jar doesn't contain duplicates files. So thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Peter I've also updated the build.gradle file, the correct one, maybe it will help someone :). Also I want to mark you answer as correct, but I don't see the option. Therefore I marked all your comments as helpful. Let me know please if I can mark it as correct somehow. Many thanks